# Task constructor vs Task.Run with async Action - different behavior

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, async-await, task

Could anyone please explain this, perhaps I'm missing something obvious.

These 2 cases seem to be identical in behavior, and yet they are not.

**Case 1**:

- Start a Task with an `async` `Action,` that does some work for some time:

  ```
  var t = Task.Run(async () => { await Task.Delay(2000); });
  ```
- A second task waits for the first one:

  ```
  var waitingTask = Task.Run(() => { t.Wait(); });
  ```
- Wait for the second task:

  ```
  waitingTask.Wait();
  ```

**Case 2**:

- Build a `Task` using the `Task` constructor, passing the same `async` `Action`:

  ```
  var t = new Task(async () => { await Task.Delay(2000); });
  ```
- Start another task to Wait for the first one (just like in the first case):

  ```
  var waitingTask = Task.Run(() => { t.Wait(); });
  ```
- Start the first task:

  ```
  t.Start();
  ```
- Wait for the second task:

  ```
  waitingTask.Wait();
  ```

The first case behaves as expected: the waiting task ends after the first one does, after 2 seconds.

The second case is weird: **the waiting task ends very quickly, long before the first one does**.

It's easy to see when printing messages from both tasks. A print at the end of the second task will show the difference.

I'm using VS 2015 Preview, which probably uses Roslyn to compile, if this matters.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Waiting for async/await inside a task](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24777253/waiting-for-async-await-inside-a-task)

Answer (score 10):

The answer is here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx

In effect the issue is that with `new Task`, and that it can only take a `Action`, whilst you are trying to give a `Func<Task>`. Here are the first two lines again, but rewritten using the correct overloads.

```
Task t = Task.Run(async () => { await Task.Delay(2000); });
```

and

```
Task<Task> t = new Task<Task>(async () => { await Task.Delay(2000); });
```

The first creates a task as expected. The second creates a task, who's return type is a task that waits 2000ms. The first example works because of the following overloads...

```
 public Task Run(Func<Task>);
 public Task<T> Run(Func<T>);
 public Task<T> Run(Func<Task<T>>);
 etc...
```

These overloads are designed to call `Task<Task<T>>.Unwrap()` automatically for you.

The result is in your second example you are actually awaiting the start/enqueuing of the first task.

You can fix the second example by

```
var t = new Task<Task>(async () => { await Task.Delay(2000); }).Unwrap();
```

Comment: This is the same as the accepted answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24777253/waiting-for-async-await-inside-a-task

Comment: This post answers your question perfectly, though it misses an important detail. You need to have a Task to unwrap. It should read as `var t = new Task<Task>(async Task.Delay(2000)).Unwrap();` Without the generic parameter, you basically state that your lambda doesn't return anything so the awaited Task ends up getting called through fire-and-forget. Your question was why is there a difference between the two. The answer is because one is unwraped and not the other. How it should be done is not even part of the question I proposed as duplicate.

Answer (score 4):

It's discouraged to use a `Task` constructor with `async-await`, you should only be using `Task.Run`:

```
var t = Task.Run(async () => await Task.Delay(2000));
```

The `Task` constructor was built before the [Task-based Asynchronous Pattern (TAP)][1] and `async-await`. It will return a task that just starts the inner task and moves on without waiting for it to complete (i.e. fire and forget).

You could solve that by specifying your desired result as `Task<Task>` and use `Unwrap` to create a task that represents the entire operation including the inner task:

```
var t = new Task<Task>(async () => await Task.Delay(2000));   
t.Unwrap().Wait();
```

Using `Task.Run` is simpler and does all that for you, including `Unwrap` so you get back a `Task` in return that represents the entire `async` operation.

Comment: Sadly `Task.run` doesn't help if you're spinning up multiple long running tasks that need to call async actions, and you need to keep a record of those tasks somewhere.

Comment: @DouglasGaskell Why doesn't it help? `Task.Run` also returns a task you can keep track of.

Answer (score 2):

Answer from Aron is not 100% correct. If you use a fix suggested, you will end up with:

> Start may not be called on a promise-style task.

In my case, I solved a similar problem by holding references to both wrapped and unwrapped tasks. You use `wrappedTask.Start()` to start the task, but `unwrappedTask.Wait()` to await it (or to access anything related to task's execution, like its `TaskStatus`).

([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18201247/cold-tasks-and-taskextensions-unwrap))

Comment: When I tested Aron's proposed solution, the inner task was never started, so if you used `await` or `.Wait()` on the unwrapped task, it would wait forever. and then, like you said, if you try to `.Start()` the unwrapped task, it throws the exception you mentioned.