# How to start async Task objects

Tags: c#, async-await, task

I want to start a collection of `Task` objects at the same time and wait until all are complete. The following code shows my desired behaviour.

```
public class Program
{
    class TaskTest
    {
        private Task createPauseTask(int ms)
        {
            // works well
            return Task.Run(async () =>
            // subsitution: return new Task(async () =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Start {ms} ms pause");
                await Task.Delay(ms);
                Console.WriteLine($"{ms} ms are elapsed");
            });
        }

        public async Task Start()
        {
            var taskList= new List<Task>(new[]
            {
                createPauseTask(1000),
                createPauseTask(2000)
            });
            // taskList.ForEach(x => x.Start());
            await Task.WhenAll(taskList);
            Console.WriteLine("------------");
        }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        var t = new TaskTest();
        Task.Run(() => t.Start());
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
Start 1000 ms pause
Start 2000 ms pause
1000 ms are elapsed
2000 ms are elapsed
------------
```

Now I wonder if it is possible to prepare my tasks and start them separately. In order to do that I change the first line in `createPauseTask(int ms)`method from `return Task.Run(async () =>` to `return new Task(async () =>`

and in the `Start()` method I included a `taskList.ForEach(x => x.Start());` before the `WhenAll`. But then terrible things happen. The `WhenAll` call completes immediately and the output is:

```
Start 2000 ms pause
Start 1000 ms pause    
------------    
1000 ms are elapsed
2000 ms are elapsed
```

Can someone show me what my mistake is and how to fix it?

Comment: At a glance it looked like it should work fine, so I tried your exact code, and it works fine on my machine.  Both versions behave essentially identically.  Perhaps something environmental?  .NET version, etc.  I used 4.7

Comment: @sellotape Works as described by OP for me: the issue is where the dotted line (representing return of Task.WhenAll) gets printed.

Comment: @pere57 - ah yes, subtle.  I read "The WhenAll call completes immediately and the output is..." to mean that the "1000 ms are elapsed" and "2000 ms are elapsed" printed immediately, when they actually do print 1 and 2 seconds later respectively.  On mine the `Task.WhenAll()` does indeed return before the tasks complete.

Comment: Unstarted tasks are a bad pattern. Whatever you want to accomplish can usually be accomplished better in a different way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Task constructor vs Task.Run with async Action - different behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28057654/task-constructor-vs-task-run-with-async-action-different-behavior)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is that the `Task` constructor you're using accepts an `Action` delegate.  When you say

```
var task = new Task(async () => { /* Do things */ });
```

you are not creating a task that "does things"; you are instead created a task that *executes an action that returns a task*, and that (inner) task is what "does things".  Creating this (inner) task is very quick, as the delegate returns the `Task` at the first `await`, and completes almost immediately.  As the delegate is an `Action`, the resultant `Task` is effectively discarded, and can now no-longer be used to be awaited.

When you call `await Task.WhenAll(tasks)` on your outer tasks, you are only waiting for the inner tasks to be created (almost immediate).  The inner tasks continue running afterwards.

There are constructor overrides which allow you to do what you want, but your syntax will be a little more cumbersome, along the lines of Paulo's answer:

```
public static Task<Task> CreatePauseTask(int ms)
{
    return new Task<Task>(async () =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Start {ms} ms pause");
            await Task.Delay(ms);
            Console.WriteLine($"{ms} ms are elapsed");
        });
}
```

You now have a task that does the same, but this time returns the inner `Task`.  To await the inner tasks, you can do this:

```
await Task.WhenAll(await Task.WhenAll(taskList));
```

The inner await returns the list of inner tasks, and the outer await await's them.

---

As also mentioned, though - creating unstarted tasks using constructors is an area you really should only be in if you have a highly-specific requirement where the more-standard practice of using `Task.Run()` or simply calling task-returning methods does not meet the requirement (which it will do 99.99% of the time).

Most of those `Task` constructors were created before async-await even existed, and are probably only still there for legacy reasons.

---

**Edit**: what might also help is to see the signatures of the 2 delegates, which the C# lambda notation allows us to - usually conveniently - overlook.

For `new Task(async () => { /* Do things */ })` we have

```
async void Action() { }
```

(the `void` being the main issue here).

For `new Task<Task>(async () => { /* Do things */ })` we have

```
async Task Function() { }
```

Both lambdas are syntactically identical, yet semantically different.

Comment: You could also write it `await Task.WhenAll(taskList.Select(outer => outer.Unwrap()));`

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you're so found of `Task.Run`. Every use of it in your code is just not needed.

I also wonder where you read that using the `Task` constructor is a recommended practice.

Anyway, without using the `Task` constructor, would be something like this:

```
class TaskTest
{
    private async Task CreatePauseTask(int ms)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Start {ms} ms pause");
        await Task.Delay(ms);
        Console.WriteLine($"{ms} ms are elapsed");
    }

    public async Task Start()
    {
        var taskList = new List<Task>(new[]
        {
                CreatePauseTask(1000),
                CreatePauseTask(2000)
            });
        await Task.WhenAll(taskList);
        Console.WriteLine("------------");
    }
}


static void Main()
{
    var t = new TaskTest();
    t.Start();
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

And that outputs:

```
Start 1000 ms pause
Start 2000 ms pause
1000 ms are elapsed
2000 ms are elapsed
------------
```

And using the `Task` constructor would be:

```
class TaskTest
{
    private Task CreatePauseTask(int ms)
    {
        return new Task<Task>(async () =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Start {ms} ms pause");
            await Task.Delay(ms);
            Console.WriteLine($"{ms} ms are elapsed");
        }, TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach);
    }

    public async Task Start()
    {
        var taskList = new List<Task>(new[]
        {
                CreatePauseTask(1000),
                CreatePauseTask(2000)
            });
        taskList.ForEach(t => t.Start(TaskScheduler.Default));
        await Task.WhenAll(taskList);
        Console.WriteLine("------------");
    }
}


static void Main()
{
    var t = new TaskTest();
    t.Start();
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

And that outputs:

```
Start 1000 ms pause
Start 2000 ms pause
------------
1000 ms are elapsed
2000 ms are elapsed
```

The problem here is that `Task.Run` understands `Task` returning functions and the `Task` constructor doesn't. So, using the `Task` constructor will invoke the function which will return at the first blocking await (`await Task.Delay(ms);`).

This is the expected behavior.