# Task.Delay unexpected behavior

Tags: c#

I have this metod:

```
public async Task StartAsync(Task process)
{
    if (process is null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(process));
    }
    var loading = ...;
    await Task.WhenAll(process, loading).ContinueWith(t => EndProgress());
}
```

and is called via a command like so:

```
private async Task TestAsync()
{
    await StartAsync(new Task(async () =>
    {
        //just for testing purpose
        await Task.Delay(15000);
    }));
}
ExecuteDelegate = async param => await TestAsync();
```

where `ExecuteDelegate` is an `Action<T>` delegate used by command.

Why does the `await Task.WhenAll` line not waiting those 15 seconds from `Task.Dalay`?

Comment: Why not pass just Task.Delay to the StartAsync? You wrap it in yet another task.

Comment: also i would say you need to await for `StartAsync` in `TestAsync`

Comment: Or do `private Task TestAsync() { return StartAsync(Task.Delay(15000)); }`

Comment: [You should **never** use the task constructor](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/05/a-tour-of-task-part-1-constructors.html), and [*almost never* use `ContinueWith`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/continuewith-is-dangerous-too.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `await` the call to `StartAsync`:

```
private async Task TestAsync()
{
    await StartAsync(new Task(async () =>
    {
        await Task.Delay(15000);
    }));
}
```

NOTE: You can also simplify your code by not creating the redundant `Task`:

```
private async Task TestAsync()
{
    await StartAsync(Task.Delay(15000));
}
```

Or even simpler:

```
private Task TestAsync()
{
    return StartAsync(Task.Delay(15000));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use the constructor to create a `Task` but the static `Task.Run` method:

```
private async Task TestAsync()
{
    await StartAsync(Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        //just for testing purpose
        await Task.Delay(15000);
    }));
}
```

The task returned by `Task.Run` can be awaited as [expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28057654/task-constructor-vs-task-run-with-async-action-different-behavior).