# Why the TaskCompleted is executed before the end of the operation

Tags: c#, task

I created a task like the following code

```
Task task = new(async () =>
{
    // without await Task Delay dont work
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
    Console.WriteLine("Task is down");
});

task.Start();

var awaiter = task.GetAwaiter();

awaiter.OnCompleted(() =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Task is Completed");
});
```

Why the task completed first is printed and then the task is down
The task is complete and will be printed if my operation is not finished yet

Comment: Are you playing with awaiters because you think it's the right way of solving your problem, or because you're curious? This isn't really an API you should be working with: that's intended for the compiler-generated code to use. Either `await` that `Task` (preferred), or use `Task.ContinueWith` (which is the older, pre-async/await method)

Comment: This is a question of curiosity, I try to understand asynchronous operations well

Comment: Oh! You've run into the classic problem that `Task`'s ctor doesn't take a `Func<Task>`. So you're effectively just passing an `async void` method to the `Task` ctor: the `Task` has no way of knowing when that async lambda completes, and it will think it's completed when the lambda returns, which happens when it hits the `await`. You need to use `Task.Run` if you're passing `Task`-returning async lambdas around

Comment: I think you're right @canton7

Comment: Related: [Task constructor vs Task.Run with async Action - different behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28057654/task-constructor-vs-task-run-with-async-action-different-behavior)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `Task` constructors are not async aware. No overloads take an function returning a `Task` so the task created via constructor and async lambda will finish as soon as first `await` (of unfinished task) is encountered.

And in general you should try avoid using `Task` constructors and prefer  `Task.Run` instead. From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.-ctor?view=net-6.0):

> This constructor should only be used in advanced scenarios where it is required that the creation and starting of the task is separated.
> Rather than calling this constructor, the most common way to instantiate a Task object and launch a task is by calling the static `Task.Run(Action)` or `TaskFactory.StartNew(Action)` method.